# how to upload image to storage and get the download link and store in Firestore and react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage

```
const handleSubmit =async (values)=>{
        try{
        
            const imageUri =values.images[0];
            const filename =imageUri.substring(imageUri.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
            const response = await fetch(values.images[0]);
            const blob = await response.blob();
            var imageURLs="";
            firebase.storage().ref().child("images/"+filename).put(blob)
                .on('state_changed' , (snapshot) => {
               
                },
                  (error) => console.log(error)
                );
        }catch(e){
            console.log("error",e);
        }
    }
```

in this function, the image was successfully added to the storage. I need to get the image download URL to store it in the listings collection

```
firebase.firestore().collection('listings')
                    .add({
                        id:uuid.v4(),
                        title: values.title,
                        price: values.price,
                        description: values.description,
                        category: values.category['label'],
                        image:imageURLs, //this is download url of the image
                        createdAt: new Date(),
                        supplierId:user.uid
})
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to watch the progress of the upload you can just use `then` to get the downloadURL when the upload is finished:

```js
firebase
  .storage()
  .ref()
  .child("images/" + filename)
  .put(blob)
  .then((snapshot) => {
    snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL().then((url) => {
      console.log("downloadURL", url);
    });
  });
```

Comment: I tried to show progress but in this progress value store 0 or 1 only.                                                                                                                           
 const progress = Math.round((snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100);
 setProgress({ progress });